# Not passing a value for a placeholder in tensorflow, why isn't it allowed?

Tags: tensorflow

I had 3 models that use the same input but produce 3 unique outputs (1 classifier, 2 regression). 2 of the 3 I combined into 1 model with 2 loss functions and saw a significant improvement in accuracy/RMSE.

I'm trying to combine the 3rd loss function into the model, so I have 1 model with 3 loss functions that share many parameters.

The 3rd loss function only applies to half the data though. I tested standardizing the labels to 0-mean-unit-variance and using 0 for the labels where they don't apply to loss function C, but that biased results towards 0 in some cases.

I'm now experimenting with alternating optimization on loss functions A & B together with a batch from the full dataset, vs all 3 loss functions A, B, & C with a batch appropriate for loss C (and A&B). In the context of my problem this is logical to do.

**My Question:**

- Tensorflow requires all placeholders that are defined in the graph to be passed in. However, I'm not using that tensor in this particular optimization step. Is this expected behavior? And should I just pass in a dummy variable to appease TF here? I wonder if I'm missing an important detail.

Comment: I think it should only require those which are parents in the computation graph of the op you are running. I have run a small example and it works like it should, but maybe when you have a complicated graph the calculation of the dependencies gets tricky for tensorflow.

Comment: I think you might be right, I'm looking into a mistake in dependencies now. Thanks.

Comment: The graph might be complicated that there is actually some dependency but you don't realize. You can also try partial run if you only need to run a portion of your graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dependency was with tensorboard, I had a summary operation on all loss functions, forcing them to be executed.

I split out my summary operations into groups using tf.add_to_collection() to gather different summary ops, then used a for loop to add them to the list of tensors to process as appropriate.

It was that and one other dependency that was just a bug that I found. @Sygi and @Fake are correct, you shouldn't need to pass in a value that isn't used in a particular computation just because it exists in the graph.